# Batch insertion into postgreSQL streaming from local file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, postgresql, io, stream

I need to insert roughly 8 million rows into a postgreSQL database from a local file with JSON objects. The code below which inserts one row at a time works, but it's awfully slow.

The JSON file is too big to store in memory (even with `--max-old-space-size=8192`), which is I why turned to streaming. However, I'm not sure the best way to read and insert rows in batches of e.g. 10000. Can anyone provide suggestions?

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool
const fs = require("fs")
const StreamArray = require("stream-json/utils/StreamArray")
let stream = StreamArray.make()
let jsonPath = "dataset.json"

let completionCounter = 0

// login details removed
const pool = new Pool({
  user: myUser,
  host: myHost,
  port: 5432,
  database: myDB,
  password: myPwd,
  ssl: true
})

// Event listener for each array in the stream
stream.output.on("data", (arrayItem) => {
  let data = arrayItem.value
  pool
    .query(
      `INSERT INTO link_list (id, url, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3)`,
      [data.id, data.url, data.status])
    .then(() => {
      completionCounter++
      if (completionCounter % 1000 == 0) {
        console.log("entries completed: ", completionCounter)
      }
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
})

stream.output.on("end", () => {
  console.log("JSON file stream has ended");
})

// Start the stream
console.log("Starting to read data...")
fs.createReadStream(jsonPath).pipe(stream.input)
```

Comment: how is this related to java?

Comment: Oops. Wrong tag. Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

there is java-script npm module `async` that has control function as `queue` where you can control concurrency .

```
function insertValue(data,done) {
    pool
    .query(
    `INSERT INTO link_list (id, url, status) VALUES($1, $2, $3)`,
    [data.id, data.url, data.status])
    .then(() => {
        done();
    }).catch((err) => {
    done(err)
    })
}

//10 insertion at same time as queue will run 10 workers to do the job
let queue = async.queue(insertValue, 10, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

// Event listener for each array in the stream
stream.output.on("data", (arrayItem) => {
let data = arrayItem.value;
queue.push(data);
})

queue.drain = function () {
    catalogUpdateSummary(done);
};
```

be careful as reading of file is faster than writing in DB , the queue will be overloaded with jobs

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm: With this npm module `data.id`, `data.url` and `data.status` would contain data for 10 rows?

Comment: @pir did not got your question.

Comment: The stalling point of my code is the DB insertion. I'm trying to understand why this code would make the `INSERT INTO` process 10 rows at a time rather than a single row.

Comment: @pir the queue will invoke 10 function call `insertValue` if there are work to be done.

Comment: @pir: best implementation would be divide you file in sub files , each having 500 data point and then reading each file in series or parallel and then each process invoke a queue.... `divide and conqueror`

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment:  @made_in_india I wouldn't advice it, first of all the `async` implementation can be done by native `Promise`. The `asyn` library is callback hell driven pattern which I hate so much. The other reason you will get some performance but with high value of CPU at server and database sides.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **COPY** command for bulk loading rows. For more performance disable indexes and foreign keys before loading the data and add them back afterwards.

For more details check [the post](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2017/01/27/getting-started-with-github-events-data/)

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll need to load multiple rows from the stream into a variable, which I can then use the COPY command on? I'm new to javascript. Any suggestions for how to do that?

Comment: any stream data you can save in file, then make bulk insert at once which gives high performance.

Comment: Don't forget to validate all records before insert them, that is why it is better to make a bulk insert into some temporary table then from it select only valid records and copy them into data table.